# Vue.js pre-rendering for SEO using prerender-spa-plugin freezes when doing - npm run build

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I've been having troubles with running the command `npm run build` when using the pre-rendering plugin on my webpack config.

I was using the webpack advanced options :

```
`captureAfterDocumentEvent: 'fetch-done',`
```

And in the code, I was wrapping the API call using a promise, then dispatching a new event.

```
`new Promise(resolve => {
        axios.get(url)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.message = res.data.short_name;
            resolve();
          });
      }).then(() => {
        document.dispatchEvent(new Event('fetch-done'));
      });`
```

By doing this, running the `npm run build` command does not throw any error but it never finishes.

Do you have any suggestion to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

`captureAfterDocumentEvent: 'fetch-done'` does not work properly...

You can try to wrap your dispatchEvent with a setTimeout like it is suggested [here](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin/issues/31)